# Repeated code and need to make it shorter

Tags: c

I'm building a Bulls & Cows Program in C and I have a code that I had to repeat several times (14 to be exact = 14 possibilities) and I would like to make the code I'm pasting right now shorter. Can someone help me out and explain how to do it?

```
//------------------------------0 B 0 C----------------------------------//

for (i=0; i<1296; i++)
{
    for (j=0; j<1296; j++)
    {
        counter = 0;
        s[0]=0;
        s[4]=0;

        if (remain[j][0]!=-1)
        {
            feed(poss[i], remain[j], f);
            if (f[0]==s[0] && f[4]==s[4])
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        table[i][0]=counter;

    }

//------------------------------0 B 1 C----------------------------------//

    for (j=0; j<1296; j++)
    {
        counter = 0;
        s[0]=0;
        s[4]=1;

        if (remain[j][0]!=-1)
        {
            feed(poss[i], remain[j], f);
            if (f[0]==s[0] && f[4]==s[4])
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        table[i][1]=counter;

    }

//------------------------------0 B 2 C----------------------------------//

    for (j=0; j<1296; j++)
    {
        counter = 0;
        s[0]=0;
        s[4]=2;

        if (remain[j][0]!=-1)
        {
            feed(poss[i], remain[j], f);
            if (f[0]==s[0] && f[4]==s[4])
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        table[i][2]=counter;

    }

//------------------------------0 B 3 C----------------------------------//

    for (j=0; j<1296; j++)
    {
        counter = 0;
        s[0]=0;
        s[4]=3;

        if (remain[j][0]!=-1)
        {
            feed(poss[i], remain[j], f);
            if (f[0]==s[0] && f[4]==s[4])
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        table[i][3]=counter;

    }

//------------------------------0 B 4 C----------------------------------//

    for (j=0; j<1296; j++)
    {
        counter = 0;
        s[0]=0;
        s[4]=4;

        if (remain[j][0]!=-1)
        {
            feed(poss[i], remain[j], f);
            if (f[0]==s[0] && f[4]==s[4])
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        table[i][4]=counter;

    }

//------------------------------1 B 0 C----------------------------------//

    for (j=0; j<1296; j++)
    {
        counter = 0;
        s[0]=1;
        s[4]=0;

        if (remain[j][0]!=-1)
        {
            feed(poss[i], remain[j], f);
            if (f[0]==s[0] && f[4]==s[4])
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        table[i][5]=counter;

    }

//------------------------------1 B 1 C----------------------------------//

    for (j=0; j<1296; j++)
    {
        counter = 0;
        s[0]=1;
        s[4]=1;

        if (remain[j][0]!=-1)
        {
            feed(poss[i], remain[j], f);
            if (f[0]==s[0] && f[4]==s[4])
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        table[i][6]=counter;

    }

//------------------------------1 B 2 C----------------------------------//

    for (j=0; j<1296; j++)
    {
        counter = 0;
        s[0]=1;
        s[4]=2;

        if (remain[j][0]!=-1)
        {
            feed(poss[i], remain[j], f);
            if (f[0]==s[0] && f[4]==s[4])
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        table[i][7]=counter;

    }

//------------------------------1 B 3 C----------------------------------//

    for (j=0; j<1296; j++)
    {
        counter = 0;
        s[0]=1;
        s[4]=3;

        if (remain[j][0]!=-1)
        {
            feed(poss[i], remain[j], f);
            if (f[0]==s[0] && f[4]==s[4])
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        table[i][8]=counter;

    }

//------------------------------2 B 0 C----------------------------------//

    for (j=0; j<1296; j++)
    {
        counter = 0;
        s[0]=2;
        s[4]=0;

        if (remain[j][0]!=-1)
        {
            feed(poss[i], remain[j], f);
            if (f[0]==s[0] && f[4]==s[4])
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        table[i][9]=counter;

    }

//------------------------------2 B 1 C----------------------------------//

    for (j=0; j<1296; j++)
    {
        counter = 0;
        s[0]=2;
        s[4]=1;

        if (remain[j][0]!=-1)
        {
            feed(poss[i], remain[j], f);
            if (f[0]==s[0] && f[4]==s[4])
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        table[i][10]=counter;

    }

//------------------------------2 B 2 C----------------------------------//

    for (j=0; j<1296; j++)
    {
        counter = 0;
        s[0]=2;
        s[4]=2;

        if (remain[j][0]!=-1)
        {
            feed(poss[i], remain[j], f);
            if (f[0]==s[0] && f[4]==s[4])
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        table[i][11]=counter;

    }

//------------------------------3 B 0 C----------------------------------//

    for (j=0; j<1296; j++)
    {
        counter = 0;
        s[0]=3;
        s[4]=0;

        if (remain[j][0]!=-1)
        {
            feed(poss[i], remain[j], f);
            if (f[0]==s[0] && f[4]==s[4])
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        table[i][12]=counter;

    }

//------------------------------4 B 0 C----------------------------------//
    for (j=0; j<1296; j++)
    {
        counter = 0;
        s[0]=4;
        s[4]=0;

        if (remain[j][0]!=-1)
        {
            feed(poss[i], remain[j], f);
            if (f[0]==s[0] && f[4]==s[4])
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        table[i][13]=counter;

    }
```

Comment: What about wrapping it in a method?

Comment: Surely, the resources you used to learn C talked about how to write a function with parameters. Your 14 repetitions only have to different numbers!

Comment: @egur it's not the same since the first one was from 1 to 14 now it's different have a look

Comment: @YannBohbot: C'mon! You asked an almost identical question, got 5 replies, and you are asking again? They used their time to reply, so at least take your time to try and understand them.

Comment: whatever guys listen we're not here to get in to a fight i just wanted to make sure if i needed to do the same and without disrespecting anyone if someone feels annoyed with my question please don't answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only change in your repeated code is the `table[i][0]=counter;` line.
Change the hard coded index value to a function parameter and write a function that contains the common code.

```
void blammy(int blammyIndex)
{
    // assumes you make counter, s, remain, f available as needed.

    for (i=0; i<1296; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<1296; j++)
        {
            counter = 0;
            s[0]=0;
            s[4]=0;

            if (remain[j][0]!=-1)
            {
                feed(poss[i], remain[j], f);
                if (f[0]==s[0] && f[4]==s[4])
                {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            table[i][blammyIndex]=counter;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: He changes also the array s, but of course a function is the solution to his problem.

Answer (score 0):

okay so let's say taking from a previous question i had similar to this one i understand that this code will help. in a case where i have as seen above on my first code where i have {0,0}{0,1}{0,2}{0,3}{0,4}{2,0}.... do i need to put it in a while loop for example? because i can't have this: {2,3} or {3,1} or {4,0}.
don't know if i'm clear please let me know and I appreciate all answers

```
for (i=0; i<1296; i++)
  {
       for (int k=0; k<15; ++k)
   {
    s[0]=0;
    s[4]=k;
    for (j=0; j<1296; j++)
    {
        counter = 0;
        if (remain[j][0]!=-1)
        {
            feed(poss[i], remain[j], f);
            if (f[0]==s[0] && f[4]==s[4])
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        table[i][k]=counter;
      }
   }
}
```

I'm posting the answer as a question because last time i edited the question to a different way and people were not happy